# Pictures in a table

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

I am using PHP and MySQL (html and CSS aren't the big deal) and I want to collect images I uploaded (the paths are in MySQL) and put them in a table. Imagine a table of 5 columns and 6 rows (30 pictures in total). I want the newest picture to be in the first row of the first column -- so left and at the top --, I want the oldest picture to be in the last row of the last column -- so right and at the bottom --.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    //Put all required/included files in here
    require_once('config.php');

    //Connection to database
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Connection failed: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select which database to use
    $db = mysql_select_database(DB_NAME);

    if(!$db) {
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
    define('DB_HOST','host');
    define('DB_USER','user');
    define('DB_PASS','pass');
    define('DB_NAME','name');
?>
```

Now, the SQL layout:

**layout.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE 'fotos'(
    id int not null,
    locatie_thumb text not null,
    locatie_middel text not null,
    locatie_groot text not null,
    primary key(id)
);

CREATE TABLE 'tekst'(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    titel text not null,
    bijschrift text not null,
    album text not null,
    datum DATE not null,
    primary key(id)
);
```

The idea behind the tables is that I upload a pic via the upload form, I enter the `titel, bijschrift, album, datum` values there and MySQL creates an ID. Then I want to use that ID to link the `tekst` and `fotos` together into the table.

How can I collect the 30 newest entries from MySQL and arrange them in a table of 5 columns and 6 rows when I want the newest picture to be left,top and the oldest to be right,bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM fotos, tekst
WHERE fotos.id=tekst.id
ORDER BY tekst.datum DESC
LIMIT 30
```

If this is a 1-to-1 relationship, then why not put it all in the same table

Comment: Waygood: Will that sort the pictures in a way I described? I namely thought it to be harder. ;)

Comment: that will give you newest first. If you want first row to be 1 2 3 4 5 (across the page) then is as easy as creating a row. If you want column to be 1 2 4 5 6 (down the page) then this is going to be more difficult as row would be 1 7 13 ... (but not impossible).

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, I will sort this out and let you know about the result! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "tekst" is, but you can :

- Add a Date field, set with NOW() by mysql, for each picture
- In mysql, do a query on pictures, sorted by preceding date field and limited to 30 result
- In php, use result from query and create an HTML table (or better a clean div structure) to hold your 30 pictures.

Comment: I already set the Date field in the table "fotos", so can't I use that field to sort the pictures from newest to oldest?

Comment: of course yes, add "ORDER BY yourDateField DESC" at your query's end

Answer (score 0):

Just order your query...

When you call MySql, make a sentence like

```
SELECT * FROM fotos ORDER BY date
```

or by ID in case are already ordered :)